# Can not install LTS 22.04 because of SSD

Tags: partitioning, ssd

My Linux PC has a SSD with 128 GB. Because of the big Swapfile of the SSD there is not enough free disk space on "/": Instead of having 2.500 MB free , there are 500 MB only free at the time of trying to install 22.04. So what can I do to solve this problem? If I want to decrease the swapfile, that would mean to start a new installation from the scratch, probably.
So I am not able to upgrade to LTS 22.04. So far I am still using the old LTS. But the longer I do this, the more problems arise with FireFox, which is crashing all the time.

Comment: "o start a new installation from the scratch" No. You can delete swap and do without on the current system if you want. "So I am not able to upgrade to LTS 22.04." what is is? install or upgrade? same applies for an upgrade: disable swap, upgrade and then enable swap.

Comment: If you only have 2.5GB free out of 128GB, you need a larger drive or major house cleaning. Lack of space is then not because of swap or swap file. You should always have some unallocated space so SSD can manage wear. And actually having a swap file on SSD that is never used works for that.

Comment: You can reduce the size of a *swapfile* easily, stop it being used, delete then re-create the *swapfile* in whatever size you want, then re-enable it. To create space, it'll depend what you've installed; did you allocate the minimum 25GB for Ubuntu Desktop? (if using 22.04 Desktop - you didn't say!)  Please be specific with details; including what size of / you allocated (did it reach the minimum for your chosen 22.04 product?) or you allocated more (the more additional software you add you need to allocate more disk space during installation; 25GB suits most users but not all)

Comment: FYI:   On systems I have with limited disk space, I usually *upgrade via re-install* as that is easier on the space as no download is required & thus free space for the download (prior to install) isn't required. That however is only an option for desktop systems, and you didn't specify what Ubuntu product you're using